# F# attributes, typeof, and "This is not a constant expression"

Tags: attributes, f#

**EDIT:** Added a more complete example, which clarified the problem.

Some .NET attributes require a parameter of type `Type`. How does one declare these parameters in F#?

For example, in C# we can do this:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Car))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Truck))]
class Vehicle { }
class Car : Vehicle { }
class Truck : Vehicle { }
```

But, in F# the following...

```
[<XmlInclude(typeof<Car>)>]
[<XmlInclude(typeof<Truck>)>]
type Vehicle() = class end
type Car() = inherit Vehicle()
type Truck() = inherit Car()
```

...results in a compiler error: *This is not a constant expression or valid custom attribute value.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should address a circular type dependency introduced by forward usage of types in attributes. The snippet below shows how this can be done in F#:

```
// Compiles OK
[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple=true)>]
type XmlInclude(t:System.Type) =
   inherit System.Attribute()

[<XmlInclude(typeof<Car>)>]
[<XmlInclude(typeof<Truck>)>]
type Vehicle() = class end
and Car() = inherit Vehicle()
and Truck() = inherit Car()
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try putting together a more complete example that gives the error? I just quickly tried something similar and it works fine (in F# 3.0 in Visual Studio 2012):

```
type Car = C

type XmlInclude(typ:System.Type) =
  inherit System.Attribute()

[<XmlInclude(typeof<Car>)>]
let foo = 0
```

I guess there is some tiny detail somewhere that confuses the F# compiler for some reason - but it should understand `typeof` (which is, in reality, a function) and allow its use in attributes.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that this *should* work. When I tried to put together a test example for you, I found the problem is not with using **typeof<...>** in an attribute. The problem was that the **Car** and **Truck** classes are defined *after* the base class.

Comment: @Wally In that case, you might need `type ... and ...` to define recursive types (that see each other).