# How do I set the owinstartup attribute?

Tags: f#, owin

I read up on a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369922/f-attributes-typeof-and-this-is-not-a-constant-expression) in F# but don't seem to be able to apply the answers here.

I have very simple code that gives the same error as the linked question. *"This is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute value."*

```
namespace MyNamespace
open Microsoft.Owin
open Owin

type Startup() = 
    member x.Foo() = ()
    member x.ConfigureAuth (app : IAppBuilder) = 
        //app.CreatePerOwinContext()
        ()
[<assembly: OwinStartup(typeof<StartUp>)>]
    do ()
```

Is it OK to have more than one file/class define assembly attributes?
If not, is it OK (not dirty) to move the assemblyinfo.fs file closer to the bottom of the project?

Biggest question, **how do I get this to compile?**

Comment: just to clarify: is this your assemblyinfo.fs?

Comment: no it isn't, it's a file just before `global.asax.fs`

Comment: ok - you should move your `[<assembly:...>]` stuff in one place - I don't think  you really want to have this on the constructor of your `Startup` class - usually you want this in a single do inside the assemblyinfo.fs that's why I am asking

Comment: In C# samples, they usually add the OwinStartup on top of the Startup.cs file, that's probably the reason. I would try to avoid it actually if your naming follows the standard conventions. (Convention over configuration-style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `member __.Configuration` it should auto detect it:

```
namespace MyNamespace
open Microsoft.Owin
open Owin

type Startup() = 
    member x.Foo() = ()
    member x.ConfigureAuth (app : IAppBuilder) = 
        //app.CreatePerOwinContext()
        ()

    member x.Configuration (app: IAppBuilder) =
        app.Run(fun c -> c.Response.WriteAsync("Hello maslow!"))
```

Additionally, if you specify the parameter this also works:

```
[<assembly: Microsoft.Owin.OwinStartup(startupType = typeof<Startup>)>]
do ()
```

I would probably just stick to a `Startup.fs` file which looks a bit different:

```
namespace MyNamespace
open Owin
open Microsoft.Owin

type Startup() = 
    let configureAuth (app: IAppBuilder) = 
        //app.CreatePerOwinContext()
        ()

    member __.Configuration (app: IAppBuilder) =
        configureAuth app
        app.Run(fun c -> c.Response.WriteAsync("Hello maslow!"))
```

Comment: Why a double wildcard?  just an x as the other code would do.

Comment: Correct, I got it from my code where I wanted to do _. but that wasnt allowed, so I added __. because I use _ when I dont care about it. Updated code for consistency

Comment: you use the `__.` to indicate that you don't care about the *this*-instance-variable ;) - it's a convention and the fspowertools understand it for example

Comment: yeah I kinda like the `__` for an instance var you aren't going to use

Comment: Its not widely used, __ "resembles" the ignore wildcard but is really an identifier much the same as x, xs, ls, this, or me.  x is the most commonly used and is the shortest too :-)